# In custom collectionViewLayout all the images look stretched

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewlayout

I created a custom `collectionViewLayout` which scales the cells proportionally to the devices screen size. All the images which are contained in the cells all appear to be stretched. Ive tried playing around with the aspectFit and aspectFill but they just distort the photos further.

[image: Stretched Photos CollectionView]

Below is the CollectionView Layout Code:

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var imageArray:[UIImage] = [UIImage]()

    var collectionView:UICollectionView! = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let CV = UICollectionView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        CV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return CV
    }()
    //Add to the official project
    var PhotoAlbumTitleLabel:UILabel = {
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lbl.textColor = .white
        lbl.textAlignment = .center
        lbl.font = lbl.font.withSize(36)
        lbl.text = "Photo Album"
        return lbl
    }()

    var fetchResult: PHFetchResult<PHAsset> = PHFetchResult()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let layout =  customCollectionViewLayout()
//        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
//        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
//        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
         collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
//        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3 - 1, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3 - 1)
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(customPhotoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        //Add to the official project
        self.view.addSubview(PhotoAlbumTitleLabel)
        setUpLayout()
        fetchAssets()

        let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        if photos == .notDetermined {
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
                if status == .authorized{
                    print("permission granted")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.fetchAssets()
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                } else {
                    print("permission not granted")
                }
            })
        }

    }

    func setUpLayout(){
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        PhotoAlbumTitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: -45).isActive = true
        PhotoAlbumTitleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    func fetchAssets(){
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fetchResult.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! customPhotoCell
//        cell.backgroundColor = .blue
//        cell.imgView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
//        cell.imgView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ManOnTheMoon")
        let imageView = cell.imgView
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item) , targetSize: CGSize(width: 200,height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
            image,error in
            if let error = error{
                print(error)
            }
            self.imageArray.append(image!)
            imageView.image = image!
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        })
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = self.view.bounds.width/3 - 1
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }

}

class customPhotoCell:UICollectionViewCell{

    var imgView:UIImageView = {
        let imgV = UIImageView()
        imgV.backgroundColor = .orange
        imgV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imgV
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print("Inside of init")
        self.addSubview(imgView)
        imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

extension UIImageView{
    func fetchImage(asset: PHAsset, contentMode: PHImageContentMode, targetSize: CGSize) {
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.version = .original
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: contentMode, options: options) { image, _ in
            guard let image = image else { return }
            switch contentMode {
            case .aspectFill:
                self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            case .aspectFit:
                self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            }
            self.image = image
        }
    }
}

extension UIImage{
    func resizeImageWith() -> UIImage {
        let aspectRatio = CGFloat(self.size.width / self.size.height)
        let newWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newWidth/aspectRatio)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, true, 0)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: newSize))
        let  newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage!
    }
}
```

Below is the CustomCollectionViewLayout Code:

```
import UIKit

class gridLayouts{
    static var screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    static var screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var xOffsets:[CGFloat]
    var yOffsets:[CGFloat]
    var itemWidths:[CGFloat]
    var itemHeights:[CGFloat]
    var blockHeight:CGFloat?
    init(xOffsets:[CGFloat],yOffsets:[CGFloat],itemWidths:[CGFloat], itemHeights:[CGFloat],blockHeight:CGFloat) {
        self.xOffsets = xOffsets
        self.yOffsets = yOffsets
        self.itemWidths = itemWidths
        self.itemHeights = itemHeights
        self.blockHeight = blockHeight
    }
    func calcBlockHeight()->CGFloat{
        //var totalWidth:CGFloat = CGFloat()
        var blockHeight:CGFloat = 0
       // print("itemWidths.count: \(itemWidths.count)")
        for item in 0...itemWidths.count-1{
            //totalWidth += self.itemWidths[item]
            if self.xOffsets[item] + self.itemWidths[item] == UIScreen.main.bounds.width{
                //var heightsInRow = itemHeights[0...item]
                //               print("smallest row height: \(heightsInRow.min()!)")
                //               print("final item in row: \(item)")
                // blockHeight += heightsInRow.min()!
        //        print("item number: \(item)")
         //       print("item width: \((self.itemWidths[item]+xOffsets[item])/UIScreen.main.bounds.width)")
                blockHeight += self.itemHeights[item]
                //  heightsInRow.removeAll()
                //totalWidth = 0
            }

        }
        return blockHeight
    }

    func updateYoffSets(previousBlockHeight:CGFloat)->[CGFloat]{
        var updatedYoffsets = self.yOffsets
        for item in 0...self.yOffsets.count - 1{
            updatedYoffsets[item] += previousBlockHeight
        }
        return updatedYoffsets
    }
}

//protocol customCollectionViewLayoutDelegate: class {
//    func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat
//    func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView, widthForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat
//}

class customCollectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout{
   // weak var delegate: customCollectionViewLayoutDelegate!

    // 2
    fileprivate var numberOfColumns = 2
    fileprivate var cellPadding: CGFloat = 0

    // 3
    fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    // 4
    fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0

    fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return 0
        }
        let insets = collectionView.contentInset
        return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
    }

    // 5
    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }



    override func prepare() {
        var testArr:[CGFloat] = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
       // print("testArr first element before: \(testArr[0])")
        testArr.incrementBy(5)
       // print("testArr first element after: \(testArr[0])")
        // 1
        guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }
        setUpLayout()
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

        // 3
        var totalBlockHeight:CGFloat = 0
        var currentgridLayout:gridLayouts = appleLayout
        var updatedYoffSets:[CGFloat] = [CGFloat]()
        for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {

            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)

            if item%8 == 0{
                print("\(item): Im divisible by 8")
                //currentgridLayout = NextLayout()

                print("Incremented by \(totalBlockHeight/screenHeight)")
                //make sure to move this down
                //                updatedYoffSets = currentgridLayout.updateYoffSets(previousBlockHeight: totalBlockHeight)
                //                totalBlockHeight += currentgridLayout.calcBlockHeight()
                ///totalBlockHeight = currentgridLayout.calcBlockHeight()
                print("Total block Height: \(totalBlockHeight)")
                print("Total block Height: \(totalBlockHeight/screenHeight)")

                if (collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - item < 8){
                    print("Im inside the if \(item)")
                    switch (collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - item )%8{
                    case 0:
                        print("Im in case 0")
                        currentgridLayout = NextLayout()
                    case 1:
                        print("Im in case 1")
                        currentgridLayout = gridLayouts(xOffsets: [0], yOffsets: [0], itemWidths: [screenWidth], itemHeights: [screenHeight/3], blockHeight: screenHeight/3)
                    case 2:
                        print("Im in case 2")
                        currentgridLayout = gridLayouts(xOffsets: [0,screenWidth/2], yOffsets: [0,0], itemWidths: [screenWidth/2,screenWidth/2], itemHeights: [screenHeight/3], blockHeight: screenHeight/3)
                    case 3:
                        print("Im in case 3")
                        currentgridLayout = gridLayouts(xOffsets: [0,screenWidth/3,2*screenWidth/3], yOffsets: [0,0,0], itemWidths: [screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3], itemHeights: [screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3], blockHeight: screenHeight/3)
                    case 4:
                        print("Im in case 4")
                        currentgridLayout = gridLayouts(xOffsets: [0,2*screenWidth/3,0,screenWidth/3], yOffsets: [0,0,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3], itemWidths: [2*screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,2*screenWidth/3], itemHeights: [screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3], blockHeight: 2*screenHeight/3)
                    case 5:
                        print("Im in case 5")
                        currentgridLayout = gridLayouts(xOffsets: Array(appleLayout.xOffsets.prefix(through: 4)), yOffsets: Array(appleLayout.yOffsets.prefix(through: 4)), itemWidths: Array(appleLayout.itemWidths.prefix(through: 4)), itemHeights: Array(appleLayout.itemHeights.prefix(through: 4)), blockHeight: appleLayout.blockHeight!)
                        print("currentgridLayout.xOffsets.count: \(currentgridLayout.xOffsets.count)")
                    case 6:
                        print("Im in case 6")
                        currentgridLayout = gridLayouts(xOffsets: [0,2*screenWidth/3,2*screenWidth/3,0,screenWidth/3,2*screenWidth/3], yOffsets: [0,0,0,2*screenHeight/3,2*screenHeight/3,2*screenHeight/3], itemWidths: [2*screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3], itemHeights: [2*screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3], blockHeight: screenHeight)
                    case 7:
                        print("Im in case 7")
                        currentgridLayout = gridLayouts(xOffsets: [0,2*screenWidth/3,2*screenWidth/3,0,screenWidth/3,2*screenWidth/3,0], yOffsets: [0,0,0,2*screenHeight/3,2*screenHeight/3,2*screenHeight/3,screenHeight], itemWidths: [2*screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth], itemHeights: [2*screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,2*screenHeight/3], blockHeight: screenHeight+2*screenHeight/3)
                    default:
                        print("Im in the default case")
                        currentgridLayout = NextLayout()
                    }


                }


                updatedYoffSets = currentgridLayout.updateYoffSets(previousBlockHeight: totalBlockHeight)
                totalBlockHeight += currentgridLayout.calcBlockHeight()


            }

            let frame = CGRect(x: currentgridLayout.xOffsets[item%8], y: updatedYoffSets[item%8], width: currentgridLayout.itemWidths[item%8], height: currentgridLayout.itemHeights[item%8])
            //

            var insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)
            //changed
            insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: 2, dy: 2)
            // 5
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            cache.append(attributes)

            // 6
            contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
            //yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + blockHeight
            //push the y insets down
        }
        print("The block height is \(currentgridLayout.calcBlockHeight())")
        print("The block height is \(currentgridLayout.calcBlockHeight()/UIScreen.main.bounds.height) screens")
    }

    func NextYOffSet( yOffset:[CGFloat],previousBlockHeight:CGFloat)->[CGFloat]{
        var offSet = yOffset
        for item in 0...offSet.count{
            offSet[item] += previousBlockHeight
        }
        return offSet
    }

    func NextLayout()->gridLayouts{
        let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(2)))

        print("rand num \(rand)")
        switch rand {
        case 0:
            print("Apple Layout Returned")
            return appleLayout
        default:
            print("My Layout Returned")
            return myLayout
        }
    }


    var myLayout:gridLayouts!
    var appleLayout:gridLayouts!
    func setUpLayout(){
        let screenWidth = gridLayouts.screenWidth
        let screenHeight = gridLayouts.screenHeight
        myLayout = gridLayouts(
            xOffsets: [0,screenWidth/4,screenWidth/2,0,screenWidth/4,0,screenWidth/2,0],
            yOffsets: [0,0,0,screenHeight/4,screenHeight/4,screenHeight/2,screenHeight/2,screenHeight],
            itemWidths: [screenWidth/4,screenWidth/4,screenWidth/2,screenWidth/4,screenWidth/4,screenWidth/2,screenWidth/2,screenWidth],
            itemHeights: [screenHeight/4,screenHeight/4,screenHeight/2,screenHeight/4,screenHeight/4,screenHeight/2,screenHeight/2,screenHeight],
            blockHeight: 2*screenHeight)

        appleLayout = gridLayouts(xOffsets: [0,screenWidth/3,0,screenWidth/3,2*screenWidth/3,0,2*screenWidth/3,2*screenWidth/3], yOffsets: [0,0,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,2*screenHeight/3,2*screenHeight/3,screenHeight], itemWidths: [screenWidth/3,2*screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,2*screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3,screenWidth/3], itemHeights: [screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,2*screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3,screenHeight/3], blockHeight: 4*screenHeight/3)

        print("myLayout blockHeight = \(myLayout.calcBlockHeight()/screenHeight)")
        print("appleLayout blockHeight = \(appleLayout.calcBlockHeight()/screenHeight)")
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
        for attributes in cache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cache[indexPath.item]
    }

}

extension Array where Iterator.Element == CGFloat{
    mutating func incrementBy(_ amount:CGFloat){

        for element in 0...self.count-1{
            self[element] += amount
        }
    }

    func incrementedArray(_ amount:CGFloat)->[CGFloat]{
        var incrementedArray = self
        for element in 0...incrementedArray.count-1{
            incrementedArray[element] += amount
        }
        return incrementedArray
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the imageview contentMode to aspectFill. I would say the resize image is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for your response, When I change the 'imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill'  the images extend out larger than the size of the cells. and completely distort the layout of the 'collectionView'.

Comment: Add layer.maskToBounds = true or clipsToBounds of true on the cell or imageView

Comment: @agibson007 Thank you that works much better. The images are a bit zoomed in though during .AspectFill is it possible to get the whole image in there.

Comment: ScaleAspectFit but you could have white space or you could crop to the dimensions of the cell

Comment: You can use `.scaleAspectFit` but then you'll end up with padding. There is no way to fit the image perfectly if the aspect ratio of the cell is different to aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: @Tom In the memories section of the apple Photos app is a similar layout of predefined cell sizes but some how the aspect ratio seems preserved without distorting the image. Do you know how this may have been achieved?

Comment: From what I can see they use fill and clip. Maybe because the photo are usually all the same ratio they can optimise the predefined cell sizes a bit better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the content mode of the imageView to .scaleAspectFill and clipsToBounds to true

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```